# main thread not execute until child thread finished

Tags: python, multithreading

Basically, I have a program where I want to create a thread for executing certain function next to main thread. But in python it seems that when I create a thread, until the create thread hasn't finished, the execution is not passed to main thread.

See the following example:

```
import threading
import time


def testing():
    time.sleep(30)


wt = threading.Thread(target=testing, name="test", daemon=True)
print("Starting thread")
wt.start()
wt.join()
print("do other stuff next to above thread")
```

If you run above program, until the testing function has not finished, the main program does not print `do other stuff next to above thread`.

Not sure if I am missing some parameter or what, but can someone tell me how to create a thread that let the main program keep its execution continue?

Comment: `wt.join()` explicitly waits for `wt` to end. The main thread _is_ executing in parallel, but it's doing what you told it to do: waiting for `wt` to end. Move `wt.join()` down a line and the main thread will instead print `"do other stuff ..."` right away.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `wt.join()` makes the script stop and wait for wt to finish.
If you want to run other things while wt is running, don't call `wt.join()` until later.

Try out this code to see:

```py
import threading
import time

def testing():
    print('in testing()')
    time.sleep(5)

wt = threading.Thread(target=testing, name="test", daemon=True)
print("Starting thread")
wt.start()
print("do other stuff next to above thread")
wt.join()
print('after everything')
```

Comment: This is basically what Tim Peters has said.